# How do I use webworkers in Webpack with libraryTaget being 'amd'

Tags: webpack, web-worker, amd

We are using Webpack 5 to build small micro apps within a bigger web app using `amd` as `libraryTarget` to deploy things independently.

I wanted to refactor some code within a micro app to use web workers which worked fine using independent dev server but once I build it with the AMD output option, it fails running the code with the following error message:

```
define is not defined
```

I looked up the `dist` folder and the web worker entrypoint is wrapped with the AMD `define` function, which is missing in the web worker global context.

This seems like a bug in Webpack but I wonder if there is a way to configure specific files/entrypoints to not use AMD, so I can get around it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `umd` as `libraryTarget`, which falls back to CommonJS if `define` is not available.